# If $f \in L^p(\Bbb R)$ for $1 < p\le 2$, then $f\ast \frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t} \in L^p(\Bbb R)$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution, harmonic-analysis

I'd like help with the following problem:

> Let $f\in L^p(\Bbb R)$ for $1 < p\le 2$. Show that $f(t)\ast \frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t}$ is defined, and $f(t)\ast \frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t} \in L^p(\Bbb R)$.

---

*My work:* I started by observing that $g(t):= \frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t} = \widehat{\mathbf{1}_{[-\frac12,\frac12]}}(t)$. Hence, $\widehat g(t) = \widehat{\widehat{\mathbf{1}_{[-\frac12,\frac12]}}}(t) = \mathbf{1}_{[-\frac12,\frac12]}(-t) = \mathbf{1}_{[-\frac12,\frac12]}(t)$. We have
$$\begin{align*}
(f\ast g)(x) &= \int_{\Bbb R} \widehat{\mathbf{1}_{[-\frac12,\frac12]}}(t) f(x-t)\, dt\\
&= \int_{\Bbb R}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{-2\pi i ut} f(x-t)\, du dt \\
&= \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\int_{\Bbb R} e^{-2\pi i ut} f(x-t)\, dt du \\
&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} (h_u \ast f)(x)\, du
\end{align*}
$$
where $h_u(t) := e^{-2\pi i ut}$ for $t\in \Bbb R$. I don't know where to go from here. Also, I have used Fubini's theorem to obtain the third equality - but I'm not sure if it is applicable here.

Thank you for your time!

---

*Note:* We use the definition $$\widehat{f}(\omega) := \int_{\Bbb R} f(t)\, e^{-2\pi i \omega t}\, dt.$$

Comment: This relates to the $L^p$ boundedness of singular integrals of convolution type with even kernels, see Chapter $4$ of Javier Duoandikoetxea's book *Fourier Analysis* for a reference. The key conditions are the kernel is even and belongs to $L^q$ for some $q\in(1,\infty)$ and it has zero average on the unit sphere.

Comment: Is the question $$\forall p\in(1,2], f\in L^p \implies \forall p\in(1,2], f*\mathrm{sinc} \in L^p$$ or is it
$$\forall p\in(1,2], f\in L^p \implies f*\mathrm{sinc} \in L^p\ ?$$
The first one is simpler (Young inequality)

Comment: @LL3.14 It's the second one.

Comment: Hi @stoic-santiago, do you still have questions about this problem?

Comment: @stoic-santiago: Thanks! I just wanted to ask if you found a more elementary proof based on tools from a regular first year analysis graduate course. Kind regards...

Comment: @Mittens Thanks for your answer. I'll let you know if I'm able to come up with a relatively elementary proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ignore if there is an elementary proof that involves only basic properties of the Fourier transform (extended to $L_p$ with $1<p<2$ and applications of Fubini-Tonelli's).

Using some classic results from singular operators (see Stein, E., Singular integrals, Princeton University Press, 1970, Chapter 2; Duoandikoetxea, J. Fourier Analysis, AMS 2001, chapter 3, for example) the operator $S:f\mapsto f *\operatorname{sinc}$ can be expressed in terms of the Hilbert operator in L$_2$, and then use properties of the Hilbert operator to show that $S$ defines a bounded operator from $L_p$ to itself (for $1<p<\infty$). Here is a sketch of how this works:

Denote by $\mathcal{F}$ the Fourier transform operator.
Consider the operator $S$ on $L_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$
Sf(x)=f*\operatorname{sinc}(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}\,dx$$

Since $\mathcal{F}\mathbb{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]}(\xi)=\frac{\sin pi\xi}{\pi\xi}=\operatorname{sinc}(\pi\xi)$

$$\mathcal{F}(Sf)(\xi)=\mathbf{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]}(\xi)\mathcal{F}f(\xi)$$
where $\mathcal{F}f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

The operator $S$ can be expressed in terms of the Hilbert transform $H$:

$$Hf(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0+}\int_{|y|>\varepsilon}\frac{f(x-y)}{y}\,dx$$
(convergence exists in $L_2$; some heavy lifting is required to properly defined this operator). In terms of multipliers, $H$ is the operator on $L_2$ such that
$$\mathcal{F}Hf(\xi)=-i\operatorname{sign}(\xi)\mathcal{F}f(\xi)$$

$$ Sf=\frac{i}{2}\big(M_{-1/2}HM_{1/2}-M_{1/2}HM_{-1/2}\big)f$$
where and
$$M_bf(x)=e^{2\pi ibx}f(x)$$
for every $b\in\mathbb{R}$.
To check this, notice that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(M_aHM_-a - M_bHM_{-b})f&=(\mathcal{F}HM_{-a}f)(\xi-a)-(\mathcal{F}HM_{-a}f)(\xi-b)\\
&=-i\big(\operatorname{sign}(\xi-a)\mathcal{F}H_{-a}f(\xi-a)-\operatorname{sign}(\xi-b)\mathcal{F}H_{-b}f(\xi-b)\big)\\
&=-i\big(\operatorname{sign}(\xi-a)\mathcal{F}f(\xi)-\operatorname{sign}(\xi-b)\mathcal{F}f(\xi)\big)\\
&=-2i\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(\xi)\mathcal{F}f(\xi)
\end{align}

The Hilbert transform is known to have a $(p, p)$-strong extension to $L_p$ for all $1<p<\infty$; that means that $H$ can be defined on $L_p(\mathbb{R})$, as a bounded operator for $1<p<\infty$: there is constant $C_p>0$ depending on $p$ only, such that
$$\|Hf\|_p\leq C_p\|f\|_p,\qquad f\in L_p$$
The operators $M_b$ are unitary in any $L_p$ and so
$$\|Sf\|_p\leq C_p\|f\|,\qquad f\in L_p$$